# Mongoose removed some data from the model.find and model.FindOne response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building an Express/Node application and I'm trying build a login controller. When the request comes through to /login, I am able to find the user details in my Mongo collection with Mongoose' model.findOne, but the problem is that what the function returns is not all that is in the mongo document.

Querying the data through Robo 3T returns all the information

Here is my model

```
{
    firstname: String,
    surname: String,
    fullname: String,
    firthDate: Date,
    identityType: String,
    identityNumber: String,
    address: {
        residential: Object,
        business: Object
    },
    contact: {
        email: String,
        cellphone: String,
        home: String,
        business: String,
        fax: String
    },
    compliance: {
        type: String,
        value: String
    },
    account: {
        type: String,
        username: String,
        password: String,
        masala: String
    },
    created: Date,
    updated: Date
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
user.findOne({"account.username": username}, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) {
            //  found user. Compare passwords and return JWT;
            console.log(doc);
            bcrypt.compare(password, doc.account.password, (err, isValid) => { 
                //  I get an error here : Cannot read property password of undefined.
                if (!err) {
                    if (isValid) {
                        //  generate jwt and send back to user;


                    }
                } else {
                    //  invalid password provided;

                }
            });
        } else {

        }
    });
```

I get an error: Cannot read property "password of undefined. 
And this is the response that is in "doc" :

```
{
    firstname: "hello",
    surname: "world",
    fullname: "hello world",
    firthDate: "01 January 1970",
    identityType: "idnumber",
    identityNumber: "12345",
    address: {
        residential: {},
        business: {}
    },
    contact: {
        email: "",
        cellphone: "",
        home: "",
        business: "",
        fax: ""
    },
    compliance: {
        type: "",
        value: ""
    }
}
```

It looks like the "doc.account" data is not returned as part of the response from the findOne function. I don't know why because I am using the data in the "doc.account" to search in the first place.

Comment: Could you show your mongoose scheme. It seems that field does not exist in the model.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet The Schema is above
The field does exist. It is what I searched with: ie: "account.username"

Comment: Oops I am on mobile. Missed that part on small screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your account schema is wrong.
For nested objects, it should be like this.

```
acount:{
 username: {type:String},
 password: {type:String},
}
```

Now this will be considered an object with properties username and password

Comment: username :String will work. Problem is your schema define acount:{type:String}. It should be an object. Or array of objects. So that it can have properties username and password

Comment: How come `compliance: { type: String, value: String }` works ?

Comment: or you can remove type:String from account object

Comment: Because its a string and string can have a value :)

Comment: your contact object is similar to account object. :)

Comment: I used the "type" property forgetting that it is a reserved keyword. What I was going for was "type" was suppose to be account type like "user", "admin", "mod", etc. 
I've changed the "type" property to "acc_type". Data is returned as expected now.